# Passing values within a TeamCity metarunner

Tags: powershell, teamcity

I have a TeamCity metarunner that consolidates two runners. The first runner does a bunch of Powershell stuff to get the right Octopus release to deploy, and it works fine. The second runner tries to deploy that.

```
<build-runners>
    <runner name="Get project release for current branch" type="jetbrains_powershell">
    <parameters>
      <param name="jetbrains_powershell_bitness" value="x86" />
      <param name="jetbrains_powershell_execution" value="PS1" />
      <param name="jetbrains_powershell_minVersion" value="4.0" />
      <param name="jetbrains_powershell_script_code"><![CDATA[

#Do some powershell stuff here to get the right release
$ProjectRelease="1.2.3.45"
Write-Output "##teamcity[setParameter name='ProjectRelease' value='$ProjectRelease']"
Start-Sleep -s 10
]]></param>
      <param name="jetbrains_powershell_script_mode" value="CODE" />
      <param name="teamcity.step.mode" value="default" />
    </parameters>
  </runner>
  <runner name="Deploy Project" type="octopus.deploy.release">
    <parameters>
      <param name="octopus_additionalcommandlinearguments" value="--specificmachines=%AgentList%" />
      <param name="octopus_deployto" value="%Octopus.EnvironmentName%" />
      <param name="octopus_host" value="%system.Octopus-prod_ServerUrl%" />
      <param name="octopus_project_name" value="%ProjectName%" />
      <param name="octopus_releasenumber" value="%ProjectRelease%" />
      <param name="octopus_version" value="3.0+" />
      <param name="octopus_waitfordeployments" value="true" />
      <param name="secure:octopus_apikey" value="zxx318ab49dce685b0ae65d94a963ff326672f51fb87c685575c3b6ed4f6eb8a569" />
      <param name="teamcity.step.mode" value="default" />
    </parameters>
  </runner>
</build-runners>
```

So you can see %ProjectRelease% gets set to 1.2.3.45, and this value can then be used in subsequent build steps - all good there. However for the second runner, on the line:

```
<param name="octopus_releasenumber" value="%ProjectRelease%" />
```

%ProjectRelease% is still equal to the default value ("To be populated" and not "1.2.3.45"). How can I pass this value to the Deploy Project runner?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, so I found a solution to this, but it is kind of hacky.

By naming **ProjectRelease** to **env.ProjectRelease** (and don't forget to add it as a parameter) it becomes an environment parameter which is updated in real time, and thus will work.

Apparently the line:

```
Write-Output "##teamcity[setParameter name='ProjectRelease' value='$ProjectRelease']"
```

...doesn't set the parameter until after the whole script has finished. Please let me know if there is a more elegant solution than this!

Comment: Teamcity now support pass parameters between runners, need "add it as a parameter" but dont need to change to environment.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to set parameters for the whole metarunner farther up in the xml.

For example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <meta-runner name="YourMetaRunnerName">
      <description>YourMetaRunner Description </description>
      <settings>
        <parameters>
          <!-- meta-runner parameters accessible in all build runners 
below -->
          <param name="ProjectRelease"value="Release.1.2.3.45"/>
```

You will then be able to use these parameters in subsequent build runners within the MetaRunner. This should be a more contained solution.

Comment: Thanks for replying 2+ years later, I appreciate the effort! If I'm understanding correctly, that will set the values globally though. I want to assign a value in the first step and pass it to the second.

Comment: Thank you, sorry I misread the question. In that case, you currently have a good workaround. Other solutions I can think of might be to consolidate the Octopus Deploy and Powershell runners into one powershell runner, or get the ProjectRelease value parameter from an upstream artifact dependency (%dep.xxx) and use that as a global parameter for the metarunner.

Comment: Up to now, add parameter in global of meta runner still not work, need to add as parameter of a runner.